# SpringBoot Junit Testing Autowiring issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to do junit testing using plain junit by calling the controller class method as below, when i am doing this, the @Autowired annotation for object creation returns me null instead of creating the object.

Example:

JunitClass:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestingJunit { 
    @Test
    public void testing() {
           APIController repo = new APIController();
           ResponseEntity<?> prod = repo.getNames(8646, 1);
           List<TestVO> ff = (List<TestVO>) prod.getBody();
           Assert.assertEquals("AA", ff.get(0).getName());
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired
private ServiceClass serviceClass;

 public ResponseEntity<?> getNames(@PathVariable("aa") int aa, @RequestHeader(value = "version") int version){

serviceClass.callSomeMethod(); // **here i am getting null for serviceClass object**

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `ServiceClass`? Especially the class declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you manually instaniates your controller by doing `APIController repo = new APIController();`. Doing this, Spring does not inject your service because you explicitely controls your bean (and its dependencies).

Try inject your controller in your test instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your APIController bean instead of doing `new APIController()` by autowiring the same in test class. As by doing new APIController the ServiceClass instance was not created/injected hence giving a NullPointer Exception.

Below should be the test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestingJunit { 

    @AutoWired
    APIController apiController; //apiController will be referring to bean Name

    @Test
    public void testing() {
           ResponseEntity<?> prod = apiController.getNames(8646, 1);
           List<TestVO> ff = (List<TestVO>) prod.getBody();
           Assert.assertEquals("AA", ff.get(0).getName());
    }
}
```